# In flutter display two users entered text from one click

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an UI where I can text from two users that are online, lets say user "A" and user "B", now when user "A" clicks on a button, his input is stored but after delay of some time the input of user "B" is fetched from API. My question is how to show widgets with input from both users:

Example: User "A" clicks on word "Add" and after delay of few seconds user "B" clicks on word "Subtract" [Note here user "A" and user "B" are on their platforms, data fetch happens through REST call/api not concerned about fetching data part just the widgets part] so the widget is as below:

Add Subtract

---

Edited:

- Expected Behavior: is both inputs (first from user of the app and second from user connected via api) should be displayed on screen but on a click of button from first user.
- Tried to create a page state variable list with bools as child elements (initially setting to false), whenever user "A" clicks add button ("add" as text of button) even index [0] updated to true so the visibility widget gets visible as true and text is displayed but UI should first show "Add" text then with delay of few seconds if user "B" clicks "Subtract" then UI should get updated to

> Add Subtract

The question is how to built logic around user "B" submitted text.
I can have another bool param for user "B" input (updates from api fetch response) but the issue is UI doesn't reflect it at the time of fetching but on subsequent click of button from user "A".
Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you edit your question to add more information? I could not understand what do you want. What was the expected behaviour? What behaviour did you get? What have you tried to solve it? Can you show some code so the person who is going to answer can test? Best of luck

Comment: To elaborate, take a good read through all of [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will drastically improve the quality of your question, and help us help you better! (No one's going to want to help if it takes more effort to understand the question than to answer it!) :)

Comment: added detailed statements, hope it is clear now.